# How to get All Active Categories in Custom Module Admin Form Dropdown in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, adminform, drop-downs, category-listing

I am implementing a custom module in magento 2.In that module I want to show all active categories in admin form dropdown.How can I show them please help me on this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using UI form?

Comment: no, normal xml way only.

Comment: Can you share the code of admin form?

Answer (score 1):

In Block Put the code to get category collection

```
<?php
namespace Sample\Example\Block;

class Categorydata extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
public function getCategories()
{
$categoryFactory = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
return $categories;
}
}
?>
```

Next You can call Block function in your Template file

```
<?php 
    $collection = $block->getCategories();
    foreach ($collection as $categorycollection){
        $categorycollection->getName();
    }
   ?>
```

Comment: If i use ui component means how do i get category collcetion

Comment: Can you post the file location where you wann display so that i can help out.please post the code,how you have tried. @Sri

Answer (score 0):

**Any custom module get the collection and shown in the select form field**

1. First, add the below code in your block

```
   protected $_categoryModal;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryModal,
    )

{
    $this->_categoryModal = $categoryModal;
}

public function toOptionArray()
{

    $productCategorys = $this->_categoryModal->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1); 
    $productCategory = [];
    foreach ($productCategorys as $category) {             
        $productCategory[] = [ 'value' => $category->getId(), 'label' => $category->getName() ];
    }
return $productCategory;
```

}

2.form field add into your **_prepareForm** method

```
$fieldset->addField(
    'cat_id', 
    'select',
    array(
        'label' => $this->__("category"),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => 'true',
        'name' => 'cat_id',        
        'values'    => $this->toOptionArray()
    )
);
```

3. Now please remove the generated and var folder using below command line

   rm -rf generated var/